# Cobbler reposync fails with 404 error

Tags: debian, repository, http-status-code-404, cobbler

So I am a bit stuck on this one, and have attempted 2 seperate mirrors for the Reposync.

Notables:

I am attempting to download via cobbler reposync for Debian 9.1 (stretch).

SElinux is in Permissive mode.

No firewall is blocking the traffic.

Wget on files in the repo succeed.

Error message:

```
cobbler reposync
task started: 2017-09-02_183335_reposync
task started (id=Reposync, time=Sat Sep  2 18:33:35 2017)
hello, reposync
run, reposync, run!
running: /usr/bin/debmirror --nocleanup --verbose --ignore-release-gpg --method=http --host=ftp.us.debian.org --root=/debian/dists/stretch --dist=stretch,stretch-updates,stretch-security --section=main,universe /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Debian_9.1-xen-x86_64 --nosource -a amd64
received on stdout: Mirroring to /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Debian_9.1-xen-x86_64 from http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/
Arches: amd64
Dists: stretch,stretch-updates,stretch-security
Sections: main,main/debian-installer,contrib,non-free,main,universe
Pdiff mode: use
Will NOT clean up.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...

receiving incremental file list
./

sent 124 bytes  received 76 bytes  400.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/stretch/Release... [  0%] Getting: dists/stretch-updates/Release... [  0%] Getting: dists/stretch-security/Release... Errors:
 Download of dists/stretch/Release failed: 404 Not Found
 Download of dists/stretch-updates/Release failed: 404 Not Found
 Download of dists/stretch-security/Release failed: 404 Not Found

received on stderr: failed 404 Not Found
failed 404 Not Found
failed 404 Not Found
Failed to download some Release or Release.gpg files!
releasing 1 pending lock... at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LockFile/Simple.pm line 206.

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 106, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 119, in run
    self.sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 165, in sync
    return self.apt_sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 537, in apt_sync
    utils.die(self.logger,"cobbler reposync failed")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 114, in die
    raise CX(msg)

reposync failed, tries left: 0
```

I may be missing something here, but it does appear that the structure of the request (folder hierarchy) does not match the structure of the mirrors I have attempted to reposync from.

I do not know where to look for that specifically, any pointers of suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem outside of Cobbler to me. Cut/paste the debmirror command from your log into a terminal window to run it interactively and see how that goes. Once you get that debmirros command working you can try Cobbler reposync again.